# Running a Perl script on Android

Tags: android, perl, interpreter, sl4a

I need to run a Perl script ([isohybrid.pl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/isohybrid.pl.1.html)) from my Android app. I came across [perl-android-apk project](https://code.google.com/p/perl-android-apk/) which seems just what I need. It comes as an eclipse project and you can build what you need from this base. The problem is that I need this inside my own project.

So my question is how can I incorporate this inside my own project? I am open to other suggestions about running a Perl script on Android too - however, the Perl interpreter needs to be contained in my APK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APK site is hosted on Google Code, so if you know how to use git, you should be able to pull the source code down using their site:

[`https://code.google.com/p/perl-android-apk/`](https://code.google.com/p/perl-android-apk/)

Once you do that you can use Eclipse's `Import` utility to import the code as an Android project. This should give you the pre-APK version of the code, which you can add as a dependency to your existing project.

Comment: I have added the perl-android-apk project to my project as a dependency. Now, what would be the correct usage of it - to just start perl-android-apk's `ScriptActivity` from my project?

Comment: From my (very quick) glance at the source code, it looks like you want to instantiate an 'InterpreterProcess' object or a 'MyScriptProcess' object - both look like they take the script to run as a constructor argument.

Comment: Did it work? I was also thinking if the script is really simple there's probably a way to do it natively in Java instead.

Comment: This part did work but the basic Perl commands do not work - see here [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291600/cant-create-file-with-perl-script-on-android-using-perl-android-apk).