# Can't create file with Perl script on Android (using perl-android-apk)

Tags: android, perl, sl4a

I want to run a simple Perl script on Android. I am using [perl-android-apk](https://code.google.com/p/perl-android-apk/) which makes it possible to include the Perl interpreter in one APK (based on [SL4A](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)). The project comes with a `hello.pl` script, which shows a toast. Alright, everything working so far, so I added some lines for file creation - now whole `hello.pl` script looks like:

```
use Android;
my $a = Android->new();
$a->makeToast("Hello, Android!");

open(TEXT,">newtext.txt") || $a->makeToast("I died.");
print TEXT "Check out our text file!";
close(TEXT);

$a->makeToast("Bye, Android!");
```

When I run the whole thing on Android both toasts are shown ("Hello.." and "Bye..") but I can't find the file `newtext.txt` anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, why don't you print out your working directory? `use Cwd; $a->makeToast("My working directory is " . cwd);`

Comment: Good point. I tried this and `cwd` is just an empty string. Could it be the interpreter doesn't support native Perl but only [SL4A's API](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/ApiReference)?

Answer (score 1):

Does your Android manifest have this?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also, you might not be able to write to that location. Other answers here indicate that you need to get the external storage directory:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Maybe you could call that in Java and pass it to your perl script as an argument?

Comment: But `cwd˙ should work without this permission, don't you agree? I am getting a blank string when I run it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure then. :-(

Comment: Not yet. Still open for suggestions.