# Can I embed a Perl project alongside an Android project in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, perl, kotlin

> I need to run a Perl script (main.pl) from my Android app. I came
> across perl-android-apk project which seems just what I need. It comes
> as an eclipse project and you can build what you need from this base.
> The problem is that I need this inside my own project.
>
> So my question is how can I incorporate this inside my own project? I
> am open to other suggestions about running a Perl script on Android
> too - however, the Perl interpreter needs to be contained in my APK.

From [Running a Perl script on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272702/running-a-perl-script-on-android)

That question is 6 years old. I would like to know if this is still possible to incorporate it in my project. In summary, I would like to incorporate a big Perl project (162MB) into my other project in Android Studio. All I need is to process data in Perl and show the output in Kotlin/Java. Any suggestions?

Note: Traducing from Perl to Java/Kotlin is not possible since the project is huge. It would take me years to complete the task.

Comment: Given that there are some instructions for compiling Perl under Android: https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/README.android it sounds possible, however I would check what libraries/CPAN modules are used as if any of your dependencies have C libraries that is another layer you'll have to deal with. Easiest may be to run the Perl code in the cloud. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have little to no experience in cloud services, could you explain how this can be achieved. To make the request from the App and extract the result from the cloud.